# QlikView Conditional SUM current value

Tags: conditional-statements, qlikview

I have a pivot table with multiple rows dimensions (District, Region, Shop) and months in columns. I need to calculate sales Growth ((sales this month - sales previous month)/sales previous month). As You can see from formula, i need a value from previous month (previous column). I have a formula for testing:

```
Sum(Total {<District={'District1'}, [Month]={'2015 09'}>} Quantity)
```

With this formula i am able to get the value from previous column (lets say i am calculating growth in month 2015 10 and District1). The problem is, that i get a wrong value, when this formula is used in a row with different District.
Is there any way to get district value of current row and use it in a formula? I tried multiple variations like:

```
Sum(Total {<District={$(District)}, [Month]={'2015 09'}>} Quantity)
Sum(Total {<District={$<=District>}, [Month]={'2015 09'}>} Quantity)
```

but none of them work

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to add `District` in the calculation. QV will aggregate to it automatically since `District` is dimension already.

If you want to aggregate all rows under each `District` to show the total quantity for the whole `District` then you can use the following expression:

`sum(  total <District> Quantity )`

The picture below demonstrate the result:

[image]

Also you can check the QV help (`c:\Program Files\QlikView\English.chm`) for the `Aggr()` function as well. With `Aggr()` function the same result can be achieved with:

`aggr( NoDistinct sum(  Quantity ), District )`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i have no problem calculating total of District. My problem is calculating total of District in previous month (i have months in columns, where each month have quantity and growth, where to calculate growth i need total of district in previous month).

Comment: Something like this? aggr( rangesum( above( sum( Quantity )  )  ), District, Month) http://imgur.com/agyZnaE